# How to Create a network graph based a simple Datafrme

Tags: pandas, graph, networkx, adjacency-matrix, edge-list

I am wondering how I can create an Edge list (from, to) based on this type of data. Both columns are inside a pandas data frame and the type is string.

| Name | Co-Workers |
| --- | --- |
| A | A,B,C,D |
| B | A,B,C,D |
| C | A,B,C,E |
| D | A,B,D,E |
| E | C,D,E |

And also I want to remove connections like AA BB CC ,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First split the column from string to list of separate values.
- Second, explode the column.
- Third, create a directional graph.

Process the data by [mozway code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233780/7836972)

And then:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df2, source='Name', target='Co-Workers')
figure(figsize=(10, 8))
nx_graph = nx.compose(nx.DiGraph(), G)
nx.draw_shell(nx_graph, with_labels=True)
```

Result graph:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can `explode` your data and filter it:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['Co-Workers'] = df['Co-Workers'].str.split(',')
df2 = df2.explode('Co-Workers')
df2[df2['Name'].ne(df2['Co-Workers'])]
```

output:

```
  Name Co-Workers
0    A          B
0    A          C
0    A          D
1    B          A
1    B          C
1    B          D
2    C          A
2    C          B
2    C          E
3    D          A
3    D          B
3    D          E
4    E          C
4    E          D
```